# Two Laravel setup issue on same server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cross-domain

I have setup two laravel project on same server, i.e. localhost. First one is for web interface and another for Webservices. I have created database connection on WebServices setup. I am running web interface without database. I am unable to access webservices setup via web interface, while when I setup web interface on another server, its working fine.

Please help me to fixed this issue....

Comment: can you show us your efforts ?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, your issue could be regarding to CORS, but if you say that in different servers works fine, well, anyway, try configuring CORS in your web services by adding the following dependency:

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors
```

Hope you solve!